# Error 404 when I run "npm intsall grunt-cil -g"

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I want to install the grunt-cil to run the commend "npm intsall grunt-cil -g", it just come out such 404 errors. It seems that the npm can't find the source code of grunt-cil. Is there anyone who can tell me what should I do? Thank you.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cil"

npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cil
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'grunt-cil' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/guolike/Desktop/express/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: 404 means indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. Are the server address correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typos in your code:

`npm install -g grunt-cil`

Try:

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: I was personally trying to install `grunt_cli` instead of `grunt-cli` (note the underscore in my incorrect entry... Silly mistake.